# Bootstrap 3 class="media-body" causes image to not be shown

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid>
    {files}
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('files/{filename}'); ?>" alt="afbeelding" class="media-object" style="width:200px">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">{title}</h4>
            <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    {/files}
</div>
```

The current result is just the title and text being shown, without the image. When I remove the whole div with class "`media-body`", the image shows. I *think* my code is structured right, I followed the w3-schools example. How can I get both the image and text to show up in the bootstrap media format?

Comment: try giving the img a class of  class="media-object"

Comment: My image already has a class="media-object"

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or link?

Comment: [Sure.](https://jsfiddle.net/59k33nsj/) In the fiddle it seems to work. However, when I run the exact same code as in the fiddle, it shows [this](http://i.imgur.com/rW91gy9.png). Without the image.

Comment: If you're testing on your local machine it could be an issue w/ `base_url` and where it's looking for the files locally, inspect the code that is rendered and check which url is being used for the images

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

**Missing "**

Change from

```
<div class="container-fluid>
```

to

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```